# Why does a pull request show extra commits after a rebase?

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

So I started with a pull request that was a few commits ahead of `develop`, let's call this branch `feature`.

`feature` had 1 merge conflict with develop. So I decided to rebase it and resolve the conflict.

1. `git checkout develop` `git pull`
2. `git checkout feature` `git pull`
3. `git rebase develop`
4. Merge conflict fixed - New commit added
5. `git rebase --continue`
6. Rebase successfull.
7. `git push` (i was actually using "Synchronize Changes")

After these steps, the PR on GitHub went from having 7 commits, to having 60+ commits.

I would have expected it to only go from 7 to 8 commits, since I fixed one conflict.

Any idea about what happened and how (if needed) to fix it?

I can post additional info if required.

Comment: "Merge conflict fixed" could really mean anything, even adding 180 commits. Check your commit tree with `git log`.

Comment: if you are resolving conflict in rebase, then you don't need to have any extra commit that is the purpose of rebase. just do `git add <conclicted files>` after resolved conflicts and `git rebase --continue` is that true?

Comment: I find that nontrivial rebases can do this. Does it help if you `git rebase develop` again just before the push?

Comment: Check with "gitk --all" or "git log --all". You may have some other branches, that rebase have taken with your actual commit by accident.

Comment: Please [don't post answers as edits to the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). Post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at your branch's git log and try to find anything out of the ordinary.

One comment mentioned using `git log`, but you can also use `git log --graph --oneline` to get a visual representation of your branch's commit history. If your branch was rebased correctly, you would see something along the lines of:

```bash
* 5eccc30d1 (HEAD -> feature, origin/feature) # Your commit message 8
* 5f73d262a # Your commit message 7
* 6c636b744 # Your commit message 6
* 97e17a7cf # ...
* 596297507 # ...
* 4646ce633 # ...
* 9fb61eb95 # ...
* 38dab17ae # Your commit message 1
*   7532142f7 (origin/develop) Merge pull request #...
|\
| * 042303c7e Add feature
* |   008f1e53b Merge pull request #...
|\ \
| * | 5a398f715 Fix issue with #...
# And so on
```

Compare with this and try to find anything out of the ordinary. The commit below your first commit should be your base branch, and there should be no commits mixed in among the ones your wrote.

I suspect there might be an issue with using `git pull` with your feature branch. If you are working on this PR yourself there shouldn't be reason to do this, and something could be going wrong because of it.

If you need to pull with your feature branch, try using `git pull --rebase` instead, which is equivalent to a fetch and a rebase, instead of a fetch and a merge. This ensures your local commits stay on top of your history, in case there are differences between your local branch and your origin.

Comment: Feel free to reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It is often more helpful if you include at least a brief explanation along with your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be your `feature` branch is probably checked-out from some different branch let's say `test` which is already many commits ahead. So even if you rebased from the same branch you're raising against, you'll get commit inconsistency. To fix this one way I know is, create a new branch from develop branch, and cherry-pick all of you're commits from `feature` branch.

Answer (score 3):

*Here is idea what could happen.*

This situation may happen when you continue adding commits into branch which will be rebased.
Imagine we have two branches `master` and `dev`.

```
master A-B-C
         |
dev      D-E-F
```

Now we push `dev` for review.
By the time of waiting for review there is new task. Branch `dev` gets new commit so locally looks like:

```
dev A-B-D-E-F-G
```

Be careful here is no C commit in branch `dev`. After that your pull request was accepted and you remotely(e.g. in github) rebased your previous changes into `master`:

```
master A-B-C-D'-E'-F'
```

By that time you have branch `master` with copied D'-E'-F' commits which starts form C commit.
But your local `dev` is different, is has no D'-E'-F' because it has D-E-F. What is more it has not C commit.

```
master A-B-C-D'-E'-F'
dev    A-B-D-E-F-G
```

**And now again you want to add commit G into master with rebase.**
The common part for both branches is A-B. So when you reabse, git do not recognise that D' and D are the same because they start from different point (for `dev` it start form B, for `master` it start form C). So in preview of new pull request you will see not only commit G but also D-E-F.

### Solution

**Quick win** is to create new branch from actual `master`, e.g. `temp` branch.
Cherry-pick new commits into `temp`. To get hash number of commit just try `git log --oneline` while on dev.

```
master A-B-C-D'-E'-F'
dev    A-B-D-E-F-G
temp   A-B-C-D'-E'-F'-G
```

`temp` branch has all commits that are present on `master` plus new G commit from `dev` branch.

```
[master] git checkout -b temp
[temp]   git cherry-pick 6e687f90 
[temp]   git checkout master
[master] git merge temp
```

**Other possible way** is to rebase `dev` on `master` and solve all conflicts. Then make pull reqest from `dev` to `master`. If there are many duplicated commits on `dev` this could be the painful process.

Comment: i think, this happen in my case. how to fix it ?

Comment: I've just add possible solution.

Comment: The other possible way worked fine for me.